# ¿Cómo convertir una string de formato '00H 00m 00s' a segundos (tipo int) en python3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, date, función-personalizada

Supóngase que tiene una string como las siguientes:

```
str_one = '03H 49m 06s'
str_two = '18m 23s'
str_three = '56s'
```

¿Cómo podrían convertirse dichas cadenas a segundos de tipo entero de tal forma que la salida sea la siguiente (de manera correspondiente)?

```
13746 
1103
56
```

Comment: Usa la funcion datetime.strptime (del modulo de la libreria estandar datetime). De allí podras usar el método total_seconds del objeto datetime devuelto y obtendras los segundos.

Comment: Si queres una respuesta mas detallada, te recomiendo añadir una demostración de que sos parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propia duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solución

```
from datetime import datetime

strings = ['03H 49m 06s',
           '18m 23s',
           '56s',
           'formato invalido']

def get_seconds(string):
    formatos = ("%HH %Mm %Ss",
                "%Mm %Ss",
                "%Ss")

    for formato in formatos:
        try:
            fecha = datetime.strptime(string, formato)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Cadena con formato desconocido: {string!r}")

    return fecha.hour * 3600 + fecha.minute * 60 + fecha.second 

for string in strings:
    print(get_seconds(string))
```

#### Produce

```
13746
1103
56

ValueError: Cadena con formato desconocido: 'formato invalido'
```

#### Explicación

Usaremos el modulo datetime, que está orientado a trabajar con fechas y horas. El plan es empezar teniendo una tupla con todos los posibles formatos de fecha. El significado de los %algo está en esta tabla: https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes.

Luego, iteramos por esa tupla probando uno por uno si la cadena tiene el formato esperado. Si se produce un error del tipo ValueError, significa que el intento de convertirlo a ese formato falló, fallamos silenciosamente y pasamos al siguiente. Si recorrimos toda la tupla y ningún formato sirvió, producimos un error.

Si hubo exito con algún formato, paramos el bucle y pasamos a obtener la cantidad de segundos. datetime.strptime devuelve un objeto datetime, es decir, una fecha y hora. Nosotros utilizaremos la parte de la hora (atributo hour), minuto (atributo minute) y segundo (atributo second) y hacemos las respectivas conversiones, para finalmente devolver el número resultante.

#### ¿Por que usar esto es mejor que procesar la cadena "manualmente" o con regex?

- Cuesta menos trabajo hacerlo de este modo.
- Este módulo existe desde hace años y es oficial de Python, por lo que (supongo) está muy bien revisado y probado.
- Al estar enfocado en trabajar con fechas y horas, el formateo hace revisiones adicionales, como que la hora sea númerica y esté en el intervalo [0,23]. Eso, junto a otros detalles, haría menos probable que termines trabajando con un dato erroneo.

#### Aclaración final

El código publicado solo tiene en cuenta los posibles formatos mencionados en la pregunta. Eso significa que acepta cadenas del estilo "Una hora, minuto y segundo rellenadas con ceros y seguida de una H, m, s respectivamente (notese la H en mayuscula)". Si querés tener en cuenta más formatos, tendrás que agregarlos a la tupla.

Answer (score 0):

Después de pensar bastante, lo único que se me ocurrió fue crear una función personalizada llamada `from_str_to_seconds` que toma como entrada una cadena de las formas:

1. `00H 00m 00s`
2. `00m 00s`
3. `00s`

De estas cadenas, la función toma los trozos específicos que contengan los números, para luego convertir esos números a tipo entero que luego son multiplicados por su conversor equivalente, y finalmente lo suma todo para retornar la cantidad neta de segundos:

```
def from_str_to_seconds(string: str):
    if 'H' not in string:
        if 'm' not in string:
            seconds = int(string[:-1])
            return seconds
        else:
            seconds = (int(string[:2])*60)+int(string[-3:-1])
            return seconds
    else:
        seconds = (int(string[:2])*3600)+(int(string[-7:-5])*60)+int(string[-3:-1])
        return seconds
```

## Pruebas

```
from_str_to_seconds('03H 49m 06s')
Out[2]: 13746

from_str_to_seconds('18m 23s')
Out[3]: 1103

from_str_to_seconds('56s')
Out[4]: 56
```

Comment: Como veo que te esforsaste, te dare mas tarde (o mañana) una respueta usando el modulo datetime. Sin embargo, no olvides que es importante añadir tus intentos a la pregunta. De ahi el voto negativo que recibiste.